# Macro to copy cells four rows apart without using select

Tags: excel, vba

This code copies the entries from Sheet1!A2, Sheet1!B2, etc. and pastes them onto Sheet2 with 3 rows between each entry. I want to duplicate this code without using .select.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    Range("A2,B2,C2,D2,E2").Select 
    ActiveCell.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy 
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select 
    Cells(((i - 1) * 4) + 1, 1).Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
Next i

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, but it is not working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 100
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, rng As Range, act As Range
        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2,B2,C2,D2,E2")
        Set act = ActiveCell.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2))
    Selection.Copy
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, rng2 As Range
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("Calculate")
        Set rng2 = Cells(((i - 1) * 4) + 1, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

I used this type of operation in one of my vba codes:

```
      'do copy from reference "Answers_Source" worksheet
    wb.Sheets("Answers_Source").Range("h1:z160").Copy

   'now paste the formulas into the student exam workbook
   wb2.Sheets("Answers").Range("h1:z160").Paste
```

So you can edit that to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Offset()` property of `Range` object

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2,B2").Offset(i - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B1").Offset((i - 1) * 4)
    Next
End Sub
```

while if you only need paste values, then it's quicker:

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Values()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B1").Offset((i - 1) * 4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2,B2").Offset(i - 1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you can just say something like "Range x values = Range y values":

```
ws2.Range("A1:B4").Value = ws1.Range("A1:B4").Value
```

If you can define your ranges using `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(4,2))` then I'm pretty sure you can do everything you want in one line